# Weak convergence of regular measures

Tags: functional-analysis

I came across the following result and was wondering if someone could provide a proof (it's stated that this proof is in Dunford and Schwartz volume 1, but I couldn't find it. So if someone knows what page I can find it on, that would also be good).

Let $F_n$ be a sequence of regular (non-negative) measures on a compact Hausdorff space $K$ that converges weakly to $0$. Then there is a positive measure $\mu$ such that for every $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that $|F_n(U)|<\epsilon$ for every $n$ when $U\subset K$ is such that $\mu(U)<\delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $\mu(E)=\sum_n \frac {F_n(E)} {2^{n}F_n(X)}$ and apply Vitali-Hahn-Saks Theoem in Dunford and Schwarz, p. 158.